# I made a function in python to add ',' after each value and insert 'and' before last value. It works but I don't know how?

Tags: python, string

```
import copy                              
def comma_code(name):                    
    a=copy.deepcopy(name)                
    if len(name)!=1:                     
       name.insert(len(name)-1,'and')   
    name.append(a[len(a)-1])             
    for i in range(len(name)-1):         
        if i<=(len(name)-5):             # I made this logic and I don't 
                                            know why is it working
           a=','                         
        else:
           a=''
    print(name[i],end=a)
```

c=[1,2,3,4,5]
comma_code(c)

This code inserts ',' after each value of the list and adds 'and' before the last value. The code works fine but I am not able to understand why the condition which I have used in if statement is working. I used **if i<=(len(name)-5):** and I was able to reach this value of 5 only after hit and trial. Earlier I was subtracting 2 from len(name) in order to use ',' this till the third last value of the string.

Comment: Try it with `[10, 20, 30]` and see if it still works.

Comment: yes it is  working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something like this (use `', '.join` to put comma between the list elements):

```
def comma_code(name):
    print('{} and {}'.format(', '.join(map(str, name[:-1])), name[-1]))

comma_code([1,2,3,4,5])
# 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
```

---

Step by step:

```
# string formatting, include the values in `.format()` into the `{} `in string 
print('this will show elven: {}'.format(11))

# Slice the list, return all elements up excluding the last one (index -1)
name[:-1]

# `','.join()` will combine a list into a string seperated by the delimiter `,`
','.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) # -> "a, b, c"

# this ill however not work for numbers, because numbers are no strings
# therefore we transform the numbers to numbers in `str`(string) format
print(*map(str, [1, 2, 3])) # -> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: thank you @andreas but I am a beginner and i am still learning to code in python. I am unaware of the use of .format, map .join functions.

Comment: @Python no problem I broke it down below my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was very informative and I learnt a few new things.

Comment: @Python; Glad I could help, if you think this solved your problem please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. This will help future readers and gives me (and you) a few points. Happy Coding!